# Ionic lazy loading issue on v3.5

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

The lazy loading does not working after update ionic .The error is `Uncaught (in promise): invalid link: DashboardPage`.

Comment: add DashboardPage's code.

Comment: import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

/**
 * Generated class for the DashboardPage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@Component({
  selector: 'page-dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
})
export class DashboardPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad DashboardPage');
  }

}

Comment: edit your question to add.

Answer (score 0):

For those who still searching the answer, Re-run "ionic serve" command and it will start working again. Every time you generate a new page Ionic need serve for compiling new pages. I think it will be fixed next major version but currently, am fixing the issue like that. If anyone found a better solution then please let the community know.